# Does the pokenav app that tell you when you've found all the Pokemon in an area?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Are there any special "hidden" Pokemon that the game will pass over unless you find them in a patch of grass? I don't know any examples but just curious. I'm huge on picking up Pokemon in each area and not leaving until I have all of them so this thing is amazing and I hope they keep it. So when I catch all Pokemon in an area it will say "all Pokemon caught" or something like that?

Edit: I literally just got the game and got to the part where there was a pokemon's tail shaking in the tall grass and you have to sneak up on it, do those show up in that app too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the DexNav lists all of the Pokemon that you can catch in each area, including the shadows that you have to sneak up on, and any Pokemon that only show up in hordes.

Comment: The DexNav doesn't list Pokémon only found in an area through Rock Smash.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to know if you've found every Pokemon in each area, a crown emblem may appear in the upper right of the DexNav, to indicate the player's progress.

- **Platinum**: all of the wild Pokémon in the area are in the player's Pokédex;
- **Gold**: the only missing Pokémon are foreign species unlocked by the defeat of Groudon/Kyogre;
- **Silver**: the player is missing Pokémon from only one of the other encounter methods (tall grass, fishing and surfing);
- **Bronze**: the player is missing Pokémon from two of the other encounter methods;
- No crown otherwise.

Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DexNav#Mark_of_completion).